# Php mysql javascript game with count down timer

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, timer, countdown

I am making a game with php mysql and jquery which involves finding out 5 differences in two images within 30 seconds. Everything works fine but some users are able to submit scores(time taken to find all 5 differences) like 0.008 seconds which is next to impossible even if you play the same image multiple times and touch the screen with all 5 fingers.

Any idea how this could be possible? Just theory wise. Below is the count down timer code.

```
var end = new Date();
var temp = new Date();
end.setSeconds(temp.getSeconds()+30);

var _second = 1000;
var _minute = _second * 60;
var _hour = _minute * 60;
var _day = _hour *24;
var timer;

function showRemaining()
{
    var now = new Date();
    var distance = end - now;
    if (distance < 0 ) {


    }
    var days = Math.floor(distance / _day);
    var hours = Math.floor( (distance % _day ) / _hour );
    var minutes = Math.floor( (distance % _hour) / _minute );
    var seconds = Math.floor( (distance % _minute) / _second );
    var milliseconds = Math.floor(distance % _second);

    var countdownElement = document.getElementById('elapsed_time');
    //countdownElement.innerHTML = seconds + ':' + milliseconds;
    seconds=seconds+1;
    //countdownElement.innerHTML = '00:' + seconds.toString();
    var strmil = milliseconds.toString();
    if(strmil.length==3){
        strmil=strmil.substring(0, strmil.length - 1);
    }

    countdownElement.innerHTML = seconds + ':' + strmil;

    if( seconds==0){
        // handle expiry here..
       clearInterval( timer ); // stop the timer from continuing ..
       countdownElement.innerHTML = '00:00';
       setTimeout(function(){
        window.location='go to a page which shows the you timed out';
        }, 1000);
    }

}

if( $('#elapsed_time').length ){
    timer = setInterval(showRemaining, 10);
}
```

Comment: they probably found some flaw in the front-end(jquery I guess) which makes them instantly submit a succes which will take 0.008 seconds processing time. I think the problem is not in this code.

Comment: I have even tried disabling JS from the browser but doing so won't show the popup to submit the score. Only when all 5 differences are clicked a popup shows up to submit the score. Really weird! but just can't find the issue :(

Comment: You are aware that javascript and html code can be changed localy to the users liking, like removing checks that check if the 5 differences are found

Comment: Yup but ateast 70-80 users did this all of them can't be web developers using firefox & firebug :) Any flaws you notice in the code?

Comment: I dont see any flaws in there, like I said this code probably works fine I think it goes wrong with submitting the time. since the executing time for your code is probably 0.008 seconds.

Comment: Some scores are like 0.001 second. How will you explain that? Seriously seems like either a bug in my code or magic! Lol

Comment: how do you send the data to the server?

Comment: When all 5 differences are spotted a popup is shown and it has a submit button. The server side has a check that without clicking on the button the entry won't be saved in DB. I have tested it and this checking of submission works. Just completely lost how the hell they managed to submit scores like 0.001-0.008 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Gathered from information the comments you gave me I think the problem is located where you perform your checks. The following probably happens in the application when this error occurs.

1. When the game starts it starts the timer.
2. The application then constantly checks if the differences have been found yet
3. An error occurs here and the application instantly receives that all the differences have been found.
4. The game stops the timer and shows the victory popup with around 0.001-0.008 seconds.
5. This entire process takes around 0.001-0.008 seconds which explains the score.

So you should probably check for the bug in the part where it checks the differences. The code you posted works fine and the bug is not found there.

Keep browser compatibility issues in mind, maybe the bug only occurs on certain browsers.

Comment: Browser compatibility and other checks are already in place. The system does not check constantly if the differences have been found or not. When the differences are found the timer stops and a popup is shown. If the timer goes to 0 the page redirects as you can see in the code I posted.

Comment: is this application online if so post the link.

Comment: Nah not online...it was online but had to take it down due to this issue. Sorry!

Comment: well I cant locate the bug if I dont have the code that contains the bug :p